# How to know email address of visitors to my wordpress website

Tags: google-analytics

I am sending emails to customer from different countries, that later visit our website (wordpress) and we want to know who of them are visiting it. Only thing I know is to use slimstat plugin for knowing about country but I wonder whether there is some way so that if a given user (with its exact email address) visits my website, I can know that.

Comment: unless the user willingly provide it to you, there's no other way :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is legal in all countries but you can send the emailadress back to you by adapting it in the link the user clicks to your website.

e.g. The email they receive has a button that links to your website.
the url of the button looks like this:
`<a href="http://www.yourwebsite.com?email='email@receiver.com'"><img src="button.jpg"></a>`

Then all you have to do is use a `$GET_['email']` request and get the emailaddress and save it to a database.

Comment: side note - this is a technical forum and not a legal one. If you don't know any specific place at which it is ileagal then the "I'm not sure this is legal ..." doesn't add anything to the answer. It is most likely that everything is ilegal or just impolite at some place ;)

Comment: as for the answer itself, it really just checks that the url has an "email" parameter. It might be enough or not depending on how accurate the OP need the data

Comment: yes, this is what I was looking for, I am going to check it and let you know

Comment: @MarkKaplun True but if the email is sent by a mailengine you van store the same emailaddress in the parameter as the email is sent to.

Comment: @Interactive, yes, but if the subscriber is privacy aware and do not want to identify himself and replaces his address with a@b.com you will still give him access. For better tracking (assuming it is actually important to you) you need also a list of acceptable email address to compare against

Comment: @MarkKaplun That is a nice extension indeed. Create an array of all the emailaddresses sent to and then when a user comes back check if the emailadress is in the array

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to get their email address without them signing up for your site first, or giving it willingly in some other way.

If you *really* wanted to, you could create a newsletter campaign and duplicate it for each person you're trying to reach, and if they visit the site it'll show up as an open and a click on the campaign. That's pretty tedious though.

A different way of going about it would be to grab a plugin that pops up a modal window when they visit the site, encouraging them to either A)register for your site, or B)opt-in to your newsletter etc. Either one of these would give you a better chance of getting visitor emails.